# To know which IP executed a certain command in linux using ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, command-history

There is a server which is accessed by many users using ssh. I am trying to figure out which user executed a certain command.

I can know the list of users currently accessing server using `who`
Also I will know the list of command executed using `history`.

But how to know which user executed a command like `cp file1.sh file2.sh` in the server?
The user has already executed the command and logged out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each new user connecting spawns a new `sshd` session with a specific PID. You could use `pstree` to print which commands are inherited from which `sshd` session, and then cross check this PID in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Example (anonymized): I logged in to a remote server with 3 simultaneous sessions, with the same remote user. I now want to find out from which IP the client came that ran the command `watch date`.

```
$ pstree -p | grep watch
        |           |-sshd(15243)---sshd(15342)---bash(15343)---watch(15450)
$ sudo grep 15243 /var/log/auth.log
Mar  7 15:37:29 XXXXXXXXXX sshd[15243]: Accepted publickey for XXXXXXXXXX from 12.34.56.78 port 48218 ssh2
Mar  7 15:37:29 XXXXXXXXXX sshd[15243]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user XXXXXXXXXX by (uid=0)
Mar  7 15:37:44 XXXXXXXXXX sudo: XXXXXXXXXX : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/XXXXXXXXXX ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep 15243 /var/log/auth.log
```

`pstree -p` shows that the `watch` command is inherited from `sshd` with PID 15243. `grep`ing for this PID in `/var/auth/auth.log` shows that it was IP 12.34.56.78 that started this session. Therefore this is also the user that started `watch`.

As for finding `history` for specifically this user, it cannot be done from what I can see when all remote users are using the same local SSH user. Also, it can easily be spoofed/inactivated/etc., so it's not really reliable. If it is saved to the history file, then you could just look for the `cp` command and look backwards in the file, but if it is not there, then there is not much to do.

Comment: It says this error `grep: /var/log/auth.log: No such file or directory` :-(

Comment: @ManuKMohan: You haven't stated which system you are on. Under RHEL/Fedora/Scientific Linux/etc., the relevant file is `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: Anderson I am using Ubuntu

Comment: @ManuKMohan: If `/var/log/auth.log.1`, etc., exist, then try them in order to see if they contain the info. Afterwards, restart `rsyslog` (`sudo service rsyslog restart`) and see if it starts populating `auth.log`, which it should already be doing. [SSHD logs to `/var/log/auth.log` by default in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Log_More_Information), so unless you have explicitly changed logging targets via `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` or `/etc/syslog.conf` (you can check to which file the `auth` level is logged here), it should be there. If not: something is up :-) .

Answer (score 1):

You can add this two lines to /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc in order to log all commands executed by bash:

```
whoami="$(whoami)@$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')"                                                                                                  
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local3.debug "$whoami [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

This will use syslog to record every executed command along with the user who did and it's IP address in a format like this:

```
Jan  8 08:43:49 xpto local3.debug root: root@192.168.x.y [29385]: ls -al [0]
```

Additionally you can add the line below to your syslog configuration ( /etc/syslog.conf ) to redirect the local3 messages to a specific file.

```
local3.*                                                /var/log/prompt.log
```

Comment: Now it is `syslog-ng` as improvement and the config file is `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf `.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy) for this.

You would have to configure it to log custom environmental variable (SSH_CLIENT) by specifying IP=%{env:SSH_CLIENT} in the definition of log message format (./configure flag or configurable in snoopy.ini since 2.x version).

Disclosure: Snoopy maintainer here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using bash, `history` will only show you **YOUR** command line history.  By default, it reads `~/.bash_history` for the history.  Note that this can be changed (though highly unlikely) by doing something like `HISTFILE=/home/userFoo/.my_alt_history`.

Assuming that you are root on the box, you could scan through all of the user's directories and read their histories to see who is running that command.

Comment: Oh, and if they are being nefarious, they could easily wipe this command from their history.  If they are actively on the box running the command, you could see it with `ps -aux | grep "cp file1.sh file2.sh"`

Comment: All the users is remotely accessing to the same username of the server using ssh. I want to know which IP has accessed to this user and and executed the command.

Comment: It's not a good policy to have lots of users sharing a username and password.